# Minimum sample size for multiple choice question

Tags: sample-size, confidence-interval

I have a question about minimum sample sizes for a multiple choice survey. I have searched around this site and the internet, but haven't found a 100% clear answer yet.

What if someone a survey was given with a multiple choice question, and respondents were allowed to choose exactly one choice. Here's a hypothetical but representative survey question:

Which feature do you want us to build next:
A) Feature 1
B) Feature 2
C) Feature 3
D) Feature 4

And we have a bunch of responses. How does one determine how many responses are necessary to achieve 95% confidence? I know how to use the formula n = (z * sigma / error)^2 for the case of two options (the binary choice case), but not an arbitrary number. I think I need to convert each choice to a binary choice (one vs. all others), but not sure if that's right, and if it is right, how exactly to calculate the sigma and error terms.